# How to use Jackson2RepositoriesPopulatorFactoryBean with child object?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, populate

I'm using `Jackson2RepositoriesPopulatorFactoryBean` to populate my bdd from json files.

It work perfectly but fail to find repository for object that are child of this repository. ( I have some object inheriting from an abstract one ).

> 'An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException:
>   No repository found for domain type: x.y.z'

I investigate and found that the Populator fetch repository from class name of the object.

My question is : is it possible to change that ? (And set it to fetch parent repo if it fail with actual class repo ?)

EDIT :

A solution could be to add a repository for each class in a package to the list of `Repositories` in spring context...

How to do that without adding an `@RepositoryRestResource` interface for each of them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems I found a solution using the `@Document` on parent class instead of on child.
This to avoid creating a collection by child.

Plus, I add one repository (`@Repository`) by child... this is not the best way to do, but this is a solution.